# Can we convert "every" value type into reference type in c#?

Tags: c#

I know that we can generally cast value types to a reference type (e.g. `Object`), but I wonder if this is true for *every* value type.

Is there any exceptional value type which we cannot box into a reference type?

Comment: Well, he's asking if there is any value type that can't be boxed.

Comment: `TypedReference` and `ArgIterator` can not be boxed.

Comment: Very good point. Care to make that an answer?

Comment: @sunside Doing so now.

Comment: Just when you think you know your trade ... well, living is learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Boxing* is the keyword you are looking for, but strictly from a .NET perspective, <del>no,</del>  for *almost all* purposes there isn't any value type that can't be cast to `Object` (a reference type).

**EDIT:** As @PetSerAl pointed out in the comments to the question and in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28928592/195651), there's more to it:

The special `ArgIterator` type, for example, contains a pointer to the local stack - which would become meaningless (even dangerous) if allowed to leave the current scope - and same goes for `TypedReference` and `RuntimeArgumentHandle`. You can find more information on that in e.g. the [ECMA 335 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm), section I.8.2.1.1 (Managed pointers and related types).

Comment: While it is impossible to box a typedref, it *is* possible to have an instance (`object`) of it being around, by using [`FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`FormatterServices.PopulateObjectMembers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.populateobjectmembers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two special value types, that can not be boxed: [`TypedReference`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.TypedReference.aspx) and [`ArgIterator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ArgIterator.aspx). You also can not have field typed as this types ([CS0610](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t93xez96.aspx)) and you can not have array of this types ([CS0611](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfca7x6z.aspx)). So, effectively, variables of this types allowed to be only on stack.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, nullable value types also cannot be boxed to instance of their type, because they are converted to an instance of their underlying type, or to null.